Understanding dBm value of FFT measurements
I am getting familiar with the FFT functionality of my oscilloscope.
I am using a Siglent SDS2204X Plus that has been firmware upgraded to 350 MHz.
Testing of the FFT function involves the use of a Siglent SDG2042X function generator set up as follows:
950 mVpp sine wave, 10 MHz, 50 Ω load and output.
The function generator is connected to the scope with a 2' 50 Ω coax cable.
My oscilloscope is configured as follows:

Channel 1:

1x, 50 Ω, 200 mV/div, DC coupling


FFT:

Configuration:

FFT mode: Average (8)

Peak to Centre

Vertical:

20 dBm/div
Ref. Level = 10 dBm


Horizontal:

Centre = 10.01 MHz
Span = 20 MHz
Start = 0 Hz
End = 20.02 MHz







I was reading the document "Understanding FFTs and Windowing" from NI, so I initially set my FFT Window to Flattop as I am measuring a sine wave.
I calculated the expected dBm value for the 950 mVpp 10 MHz sine wave to be 3.534 dBm rounded to 3 decimal places.
When I measure my sine wave on the scope, I get a value of 3.538 using the Flattop window (see screenshot below).  However, while playing with the horizontal time division knob I notice that the measured dBm value of the center frequency changes.  I also notice that the measured dBm value is significantly affected by the window type selected.  Below is a chart of values I recorded for the Flattop and Hanning window types.  Flattop seemed reasonable across the time/div ranges I used, but the dBm value varied considerably for the Hanning window.  I also found the dBm values were different when I selected the Hamming window, but did not record these values.


Why does the measured dBm value change with the time/div and not line up with the expected (calculated) value?  Why does the dBm value change with the selected window type?  For that matter, why is the measure frequency not matching the channel input measurement of 10 MHz?  I am asking this as I plan to do some near field measurements later and would like to know that the measurements I am taking are accurate/reliable.

A window is a function multiplied by your input. If you multiply your input by a function then the value of your input changes. There are correction factors that can be used for different windows, or you can use flat top.
Your FFT is actually showing you energy per frequency, and FFTs are usually programmed to conserve energy. When you change the sampling frequency you change width of the bin you are summing energy over and so change the peak amplitude so that the energy of the bin remains correct. If you for example doubled the width of your frequency bin but kept the peak amplitude unchanged the total energy (width times height) would be doubled.

For measuring amplitude in an FFT, the flat top window is recommended.
For looking at spectra detail a Hamming, or something similar like Hann or Blackman-Harris, is recommended but may suffer from slight amplitude errors.
When you change the horizontal sweep rate, you are also changing the sampling rate of the oscilloscope which can affect amplitude readings (depends if the signal is split between frequency bins) and other characteristics of the displayed FFT.
Setting up an oscilloscope to perform an FFT is full of traps and you need to experiment with the scope to understand its capabilities. Different oscilloscope models behave differently even within the same manufacturer's product selection.
You may get better details if you reduce the frequency span of the FFT. Using a 20 MHz frequency span for a sine wave will hide detail unless you are looking for harmonics.
